Creating Blazor project from command line is giving warnings in VS Code
I have created a project in .NET 8 Blazor web app using command
dotnet new blazor -o ProductBlaze
Opening in VS Code is giving me warning such as
Found markup with unexpected name 
Routes.razor
Solution Explorer
I tried upgrading C# dev kit extension and .NET Install. But it is not working.
_Imports.razor
    @using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using ProductBlaze
@using ProductBlaze.Components

Counter.razor
@page "/counter"
    @rendermode InteractiveServer // The name 'InteractiveServer' does not exist in the current context
    
    <PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
    
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    
    <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    
    @code {
        private int currentCount = 0;
    
        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }
    }


Please include your Imports.razor file in your question. Also you should include the questionable code directly in your question instead of an image. For me it works just fine

Thanks Aaron. Updated the description. In code, I am getting warning of "Found markup element with unexpected name 'PageTitle'. If this is intended to be a component, add a @using directive for its namespace." built in components.

Hi @JOYBOY, have you tried clean and rebuild the project?

@Rena I did clean and rebuild the project. Also removed bin and obj manually but still issue persists.

Hi @JOYBOY, could you pls share the minimal repo with us?

Hi @JOYBOY, what if you add @using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode  in your current component? Still the same issue?

I'm getting problems on my existing project to a similar effect. I'm able to use Visual Studio but not VS Code as I'm getting CS0234 errors on every @using in my razor files.

@DannyHepple I had tried with VS Code of Github Codespaces by creating tempate Blazor Web App project. Having similar issue. So don't know how to solve this issue.
